# Bash - to print keys and values from a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Given:

```
array(a1)=123
array(b1)=456
```

My command is:

```
for test in ${array[@]}; do
   echo "Hello "$!test "$test" Hi"
done
```

The output is:

```
Hello test 123 Hi
Hello test 456 Hi
```

Expected output is:

```
Hello a1 123 Hi
Hello b1 456 Hi
```

Comment: When asking questions, please make sure to format it in a readable way. Code blocks are marked by indenting them by 4 spaces. When editing, you can see a preview of your question below the editing area.

Comment: noted on this bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is a normal variable and doesn't store any reference to the array. In your case writing `$!test` is the same as writing `${someUndefinedVariable}test` (see ✱). The undefined variable will expand to the empty string. `test` is a literal string.

To print the keys and values, you have to iterate over the keys and retrieve the corresponding values manually:

```
declare -A array
array[a1]=123
array[b1]=456
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do
    echo "key=$key, value=${array[$key]}"
done
```

By the way, I'm suprised your command even ran without an error; a closing `"` is missing. You cannot nest quotation marks. After the first `"` the second `"` will end quotation:

```
|quoted|       |quoted   |started quote without end -->
|      |       |     |   |
"Hello "$!test "$test" Hi"
       |       |     |   | 
       |unquoted     |unquoted
```

✱ `$!` is actually a special variable that contains the process number of the last background command. Since you did not start any background commands in your session `$!` is empty.

Comment: hmmm, not the answer im looking for. do you have any other method?

Comment: Not really. This is the only safe and portable way. What bugs you about this approach?

Comment: The reason I asked for this question is i want to assign two variables inside for loop, var1=key and var2=its corresponding value


The logic is like this:

For test in ${array[@]} and keytest in ${!array[@]}; do

echo "  $test $keytest "

Comment: Then I don't see the problem, you only have to write `${array[$keytest]}"` instead of `test`. If that annoys you, you can always define a new variable: `for keytest in "${!array[@]}"; do test=${array[$keytest]}; echo "$test $keytest"; done`.